# Does console.error stops the code execution when fired?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program which loads a file and run some functions on it. Multiple files can be loaded.

If there's an error loading the file, like a misspelling of the name, I log a `console.error`. But I don't want to stop the execution.

Does `console.error` stops the execution? Does `throw new error` can be an alternative? Or should I use `console.warn`?

Comment: Did you try it out? Make a small dummy script to see what happens?

Comment: [`console.error()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error): _"Outputs an error message to the Web Console"_

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey Thanks for the idea! I didn't get that in mind and tried it out in the browser console!

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey it's more convenient for future readers to have a SO question about this, so this question is still very valid. Plus, different browsers could behave differently, so a dummy script would not be conclusive

Comment: `console.error` doesn't throw, but `throw` does produce (in Chrome, at least) the same red squiggles and circle-X that `console.error` does, producing a similar UI and perhaps Pavlovian response from developers `;^D`. So if you're looking in the dev tools console, you might be forgiven for assuming something similar has happened.

Answer (score 9):

> Does console.error stops the execution?

No

> Does throw new error can be an alternative?

Yes, as follow: `throw new Error("Message");`